# Adobe Air Application - open facebook app to login

Tags: android, ios, facebook, actionscript-3, air

I want my adobe air app to open my user's Facebook app installed on their own device and return to my adobe air app and finish the login process.

I don't want to open Facebook with stagewebview(because the user has to login once more). i want to make it done as other native apps do their Facebook logins.

if this is possible, i want to know how

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727572/facebook-abobe-as3-api-for-air-for-mobile

Comment: i don't want it be done by "stagewebview" it makes my users to log in once more

Comment: There's also a native extension at that post; although, I just realized that extension is commercial.  There are other native extensions available.

Comment: I never tried ane. not sure it will figure out...I'll try though. thx!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a native extension to achieve this, there are many out there, but just going to point you in the direction of the one we've developed and use in our applications:

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.FacebookAPI

> **The facebook utils extension has been discontinued so the following is no longer applicable, please look into the FacebookAPI ANE above**
>
> > Or there's the simpler one that just does single sign on if you don't need access to all the API (i.e. if you're going to use the AS3 facebook lib):
> >
> > http://distriqt.com/product/air-native-extensions/facebook-utils

Cheers

Comment: links are broken. http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.FacebookAPI

Answer (score 0):

You can use FreshPlanet Facebook ANE from here https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook

If users have Facebook app then works exactly you want it. Also supported SSO login.